# Speed up OTA time for MCU

Tags: stm32, bootloader

I'm trying to update the code on a STM32F407vgt06 mcu using OTA. Using python code, the new program is sent in packets of 128 bytes through MQTT and the bootloader on the mcu checks the crc and then writes it into the flash. The issue is that it takes upto 4 hours to update the mcu. I was wondering if there was a way to improve the performance of the OTA download or is it possible to use MQTT to update the mcu, would it be better to use FTP instead.

Comment: If it takes 4 hours you're only transmitting once every 2 seconds. Why isn't this in the milliseconds?

Comment: You could also increase the packet size. You can put up to about 1500 bytes into a single packet. 4 hours sounds like some other kind of issue though, are you doing this over a cellular connection?

Comment: I'm doing this over cellular

Comment: What generation? 2G? GPRS or EDGE?

Comment: I'm using a 4G Cat 4 modem